sGTM's /gtm/debug mode throw 400 Bad Request
I'm starting with migration from GTM so Server GTM. I have set up everything in Google Cloud Run with Loadbalancer for our testing-env and everything works fine.
Now I've setup everything for our production system but the GTM Debug mode is not working and throw's Error 400 Bad Request - I use the same setting and config as in the testing-env:

The state in https://sst.myserver.com/healthz says also OK.
After some search for the error in the web, some say that if the server throw's 400, a client is missing. But I've connected also GA4 with it and the data is coming to GA4. Only the debug mode is not working under /gtm/debug/...
Any ideas?

Is it a CSP issue? (https://github.com/jonashaag/content-security-policy-rules/blob/master/google-tag-manager.md)

To help debug this we may need further information: what do your testing and production envs looks like? Are they separate Cloud Run services, is there a separate service for the tagging server and the preview server, were they provisioned automatically or manually?

Yes. They are seperate services in two different projects.
sst-staging with tagging and preview server instances and sst-production with tagging and preview instances. And currently they are provisioned manually.

No not a CSP issue since I mean the Server-GTM debug mode and not the Web-GTM debug mode

Finally I found the issue. The preview-server did not run correctly as preview-server. In Cloud Run the env var name 'RUN_AS_PREVIEW_SERVER ' had an empty space which lead that the preview server was startet as regular server. And the regular server is not allowed handle the /gtm/debug request correctly.
